# MYSQL triggers to keep same data in two tables

Tags: mysql, triggers

for many reasons I need to have same data in two tables. I'm starting new system, and for short period i need to have both systems running, the problem is old system have not so good MySQL structure so a can't keep it as it is. I don't want to changing old or new system configuration. I thought he best solution is put some triggers on both old and new table something like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS table1_table2;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `table1_table2` AFTER INSERT ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF(@disable_triggers != 1) THEN
        SET @disable_triggers = 1;
        INSERT INTO table2 (value1,value2)
        VALUES( NEW.value1, NEW.value2 );
    END IF;
    SET @disable_triggers = 0;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS table2_table1;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `table2_table1` AFTER INSERT ON `table2`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF(@disable_triggers != 1) THEN
        SET @disable_triggers = 1;
        INSERT INTO table1 (value1,value2)
        VALUES( NEW.value1, NEW.value2 );
    END IF;
    SET @disable_triggers = 0;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

at first try i create triggers without IF conditions and it failed, because table1 is locked so second trigger can not write to it. I decide to add @disable_triggers global variable to prevent running triggers in cycles, but after insert nothing happened , any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need two tables? Drop one and replace it with a view

Comment: thank you, i hope everything will work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to e4c5. Best solution is create VIEW:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t2col1` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `t2col2` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `table2` (`t2col1`, `t2col2`)
SELECT `t1col1`, `t1col2` FROM `table1`; 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `table1` AS
SELECT `t2col1` AS `t1col1`, `t2col2` AS `t1col2`
FROM `table2`;
```

both queries have same result

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `table2`;
```

it's the same with INSERT